# Bakoma - how to view errors

Tags: errors, bakoma

When my latex doc has errors, Bakoma displays the arrows at the bottom right corner used to navigate between errors, but I cannot see what is the actual error - I do not see a console window and do not know how to view it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't use Bakoma and there are 4 questions till date with bakoma tag and zero following it. But simply include the screenshot image with errors so that wider user audience can help you. Help others to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the menu bar, select "Window", and make sure that "Working Files" is checked. Then you should be able to see a `*Console*` tab that contains the LaTeX messages.

[image: BaKoMa console tab screenshot]

Comment: How do you push the source file window to the rightmost? Would you please?

Comment: @Chou: Just use click-and-drag `:)`